# Publishing an InfoPath form wiped out Personal Views in the Form Library

Tags: infopath

I published an InfoPath 2007 form into a Form Library on MOSS 2010 and I lost all the data in the form column fields.  I was able to restore the data by doing a check-out/Check-in on the documents, but now realized it has screwed up the personal view that were created in that library.  The views no longer contain the filers or column that referred to the columns of the form data.  Any clue why this happened or how we can restore the personal views other then recreating them?

Comment: Is it possible that this is addressed in a service pack, cumulative update, or hotfix?

Comment: I experienced the same issue. I struggled for weeks trying to figure out how to update a 2007 InfoPath form in SharePoint 2010 without having to reopen each form and recreate each view. I found Dave's solution of re-promoting each field and specifying the existing column in the selected library to be simple and effective. Thanks, Dave. This saved me hours of work and allowed me to make changes to the form I wouldn't have been able to make without this solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably facing the issue described in KB article [2554288 Columns published from InfoPath fields are recreated when the same InfoPath form template is re-published to more than one document libraries in a SharePoint site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2554288/). The issue is that InfoPath isn't very flexible when it comes to matching up columns in SharePoint with what it's expecting in the form. It has probably duplicated all of the columns in the list.

The only way I know to resolve this is from backup or painstakingly cleaning up the mess.

Answer (score 3):

The KB article Alex linked above offers one (theoretically) good solution: Publish the form as a Site Content Type and then associate that with the library.

After running into this today when publishing an updated form into a Test environment, I decided to try another solution when publishing into Production (you only live once), which worked well:

When in the publishing wizard and selecting fields to promote, go through the full list and Modify each field which already exists in the destination library: change the Site Column Group from "(None: Create new column...)" to "(This document library)" and then select the existing column.

I'm guessing that the safest practice for any forms deployed this way is to go through the Promotion list every time you change the environment/site/library you're publishing to and switch everything to "...Create new column..." (if not already set) and then change to "(This ... library)" to force the internal column GUID to be set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues and the problem is related to how you publish your form. When I republished the form, the list view lost all lookup fields in the form and I had to add them again. Also any list view webpart containing these coloums needed to be updated. Also I needed to reopen all forms and save them again in order to have the lookup field information available in the SharePoint list.

To solve this problem i publish the form as a content type instead. I found this blog which describes step by step how to do this.

http://www.marclenferna.com/blog/archive/2009/01/18/how-to.-publish-your-infopath-form-to-sharepoint--a.aspx

Basically you upload the form as a content type to an new list which is only to contain the contenttype and then you create a new form library where you add the new content type.